# How to know which privilages a user has based on AccessRightMask value in PrincipalObjectAccess

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We need to find out how many records (rows) for a particular entity in CRM 2011 have write privileges using the AccessRightsMask column in the PrincipalObjectAccess (POA) table in SQL.

In the enumerator for AccessRights in CrmSdk the mask value for WriteAccess is given as 2, but when we search for a value of 2 on POA table there are no records found for this AccessRightsMask value.

What query should we be using to return the rows where a user or team has write access to the object?

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly won't find many objects where principals only have write access, since read access would almost always be required to go with it and a whole bunch of other stuff.
You are treating this as a mask aren't you? ie not looking for values = 2 but second-to-last bit = 1 ?
Your query wants to be something like:

`select foo from <POA table> where AccessRightsMask & 2 =2`

And the POA table, as far as I know, only records access rights which are outside the normal security model ie records which have been explicitly shared, or where rights have been cascaded on re-parenting. 'Normal' access is figured out on the fly according to security roles, team membership, BU of the principal relative to the object and so on.

I do feel a need to ask the big question - "why do you need to try and get this information, and why this approach?"

Comment: Thanks @AdamV. Actually we have shared the records programatically with our own rolemangement.We defined roles and their access on few entities like read,write,delete,share....In our sharing few of the records which are not supposed to be given Write Access are given with Write access . So we just wanted to analyse the records what was wrong in our sharing part.